# Extract frame from .hevc video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, h.265

I use the following command to create a snapshot 10 hours into a video:

`ffmpeg -y -ss 36000.0 -i INPUT -frames:v 1 -q:v 1 output.png`

But I'm running into an issue where this command doesn't work with .hevc files, and I get this error message:

> [in#0/hevc @ 0x6000033a4000] could not seek to position 36000.0

I found that moving the -ss flag after the -i flag like this:

`ffmpeg -y -i INPUT -ss 36000.0 -frames:v 1 -q:v 1 output.png`

solves the problem, but it significantly increases the execution time from less than a second to several minutes.

I'm looking for a way to improve the performance while maintaining the highest possible output quality. Do you know of any ffmpeg commands or perhaps a combination of ffmpeg and ffprobe commands that could help speed things up? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Adding `-skip_frame nokey` is faster, but less accurate: `ffmpeg -y -skip_frame nokey -i input.265 -ss 36000.0 -frames:v 1 -update 1 output.png`. I think that the fastest way is maybe converting to MP4 using `-c copy`: `ffmpeg -y -skip_frame nokey -i input.265 -c copy tmp.mp4` and then seek the temporary MP4 file: `ffmpeg -y -ss 36000.0 -i tmp.mp4 -frames:v 1 -update 1 output.png`

Comment: Thank you! That is indeed much faster.